# I want to wait synchronously for an IP address change

Tags: c++, macos, networking

I would like to implement a function to wait for IP address changes synchronously in C++.

On Windows, I was able to implement the desired functionality with

```
NotifyAddrChange (NULL, NULL);
```

It could not be implemented successfully on MacOS.

For example:

```
while (1) {
    NotifyAddrChange(NULL, NULL);
    /* any code */
}
```

> IPHlpApi.h　NotifyAddrChange()
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-notifyaddrchange

Comment: What about invoking getifaddrs in a loop every few seconds until the result changes?  Also, what are you really trying to anyway?  Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Well, that's the Windows API not the OS-X API, so using that function's obviously not an option. Now, you could try to find an adaption layer implementing one API on top of the other or at least gain some insights studying the code. BTW: As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I asked a question because there was no good way. In fact, you may not have a good way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect IP address change on OSX programmatically in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532144/how-to-detect-ip-address-change-on-osx-programmatically-in-c-or-c)

Comment: I saw that question but it could not solve my problem, because I can't see the C ++ sample code.